# Reservation system design

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I'm working on a reservation system schema and have some problems defining availability of resources. I searched for similar question here and on Google but still don't have clear understanding

My app is for booking taxis. Where each taxi driver is either working today or taking a day off. So far I have come up with the following structure

```
table: Drivers
id INT PRIMARY KEY
name INT

table: Users
id INT PRIMARY KEY
name TEXT

table: Reservations
id INT PRIMARY KEY
start: DATETIME
end: DATETIME
userID: INT (FOREIGN KEY(Users.id))
driverID: INT (FOREIGN KEY(Drivers.id))
```

I was thinking of treating each driver as available if there is no reservation entry, and then coming up with different types of reservations:

Unavailable => driver is taking a day off Booked => driver is booked by a user between start/end times Cancelled => cancelled booking

However, maintaining Unavailable/Booked status sounds a bit more complicated than I'd like to.

So, are there any suggestions how to improve the database schema?

Comment: This is pretty standard approach. A driver is either unavailable (with the reason specified in the reservation table - holidays, booked, etc.) or he is available (not in the table). Can you expand on "maintaining Unavailable/Booked status sounds a bit more complicated than I'd like to" - whats the actual problem. It's a _good_ idea to extend your reservation table to contain all different types because you can just add to them later, i.e. sick, no car available etc. and as you've said you can include a cancelled flag to identify cancellations

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to avoid the driver availability (because he is off / taxi is in repair) is to add a boolean property in the Drivers table which can be turned on or turned off from the UI.

And Reservation should have a property as cancelled, so that when querying for available drivers cancelled reservations can be ignored.

So the available drivers would be

```
select *
from drivers d
where d.Available = true
and not exists (
  select top(1) r.id
  from rerservations r
  where r.driverid = d.id
  and r.cancelled = false
  and r.start < GetDate()
  and r.end > GetDate()
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, what if a driver goes on vacation next week? With this design I'd have to set his status to 'not available' precisely next Monday. And not forget to put it back to 'available' when his back. I'm looking for a more flexible solution which would allow me to set resource availability in future

Comment: If you add a cancelled reservation, it should work. It's not nice though, but if you named it a bit differently (such as allocations rather than reservations where allocation is a superclass of reservation and userid is not applicable to allocation)

Comment: What about a non-availability tracking table? When driver goes on vacation or takes a break, make an entry with from and to timestamps. When his taxi is reserved, make an entry. May be use a reason/status flag also to say why he is not available. When someone cancels a booking, you can delete that record from the non-availability table. There are very useful timestamp functions available in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Sounds good, only thing is deleting of reservation is not good, as you might want to see how many of them cancelled, so I'd keep a flag than delete it